# Issue with getCallbackTokenAsync function on hosted exchange

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, office-js

I'm facing some issues with the `Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync()` function for Office.js.

I am using this function to generate a token which I then use to get the attachments data of the email. For some reason though when I am using the outlook mail client with an exchange hosted email server the function always returns the following error `The user is no longer connected to the network. Please check your network connection and try again`. If I use a regular hotmail email OR I log in to my hosted exchange email via web browser, the function succeeds and returns the token. Only in Outlook desktop mail client with exchange emails do I get this error.

Permissions in my manifest are set to `ReadWriteMailbox`
using Microsoft Office 365 Business
using Office version `http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1`

Is the function simply not available to use for exchange hosted emails, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Thanks for the info about the repro. Which version of Outlook Desktop are you running, and which version of Exchange Server are you connected to?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Outlook for Office 365 and the Exchange 2016

Comment: Do you see a request being made if you attach fiddler to outlook? What do you see as part of the response in fiddler?

Comment: after attaching Fiddler, I have found the following error is returned `[Fiddler] DNS Lookup for "w4-exmbx01.wpl4.com" failed. System.Net.Sockets.SocketException No such host is known` and the response code is 502

Comment: as far as I am aware the `w4-exmbx01` part of the request url is not a sub-domain of our mail server

Comment: On your server could you run "Get-WebServicesVirtualDirectory |fl" and see what the Internal & External Url point to?

Comment: these are the results:
`InternalUrl: https://w4-exmbx03.wpl4.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx`
`ExternalUrl: https://mail.wpl4.com/ews/exchange.asmx`

Comment: is there another way to get attachment data from the mail client for exchange servers? I need to upload the attachment to our server where the data is parsed from it.

Comment: There is no other way to get attachment data via the add-in. Can you test this in OWA with fiddler attached and provide the request url? The client does not manipulate the url. Make a simple add-in that displays a button that calls `Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync()`. Is it possible to provide a test account for us to log in and test the add-in? Also, does this impact all accounts on the hosted server or just this one?

Comment: this is the request url in OWA:
`https://mail.wpl4.com/owa/service.svc?action=GetClientAccessToken&EP=1&UA=0&ID=-145&AC=1`

Comment: we have a test account available. please let me know how best to send this over to you. regarding the impact on hosted servers, we can't say for sure if every exchange user is experience issues, however everyone who has reported an issue is using hosted exchange

Comment: Desktop Outlook will use the Internal URL first, then should fallback on the External URL if both Urls are made known to the client via Autodiscover. In your fiddler traces are is there a request to the mail.wpl4.com... address? Also we would guess that if w4-exmbx0X is returning a 502 bad gateway, then there is something wrong with the server, which is unfortunately outside our area of expertise.

Comment: there are no requests being made to mail.wpl4.com... addresses withing outlook desktop client only the address specified above. I have noticed that when attaching a fiddler to the desktop, even upon launch there are several requests to `w4-exmbx0X.wpl4.com` domains, all of which seem to be returning 502 errors. would this then indicate that we need to contact our exchange providers to configure our mail server properly? we have a number of customers reporting the feature not working also

Answer (score -1):

Which version of Outlook Desktop and Exchange server are you using?

According to my search, getCallbackTokenAsync function is supported in client outlook 2013.

For more information, please review the following link:

[Is getCallbackTokenAsync supported in client outlook?](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/9ccf6e91-3846-4e69-a452-84c522005448/is-getcallbacktokenasync-supported-in-client-outlook?forum=appsforoffice)

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Outlook for Office 365 MSO(16.0.10830.20088) and Exchange 2016 version 15.1 (build 669.32)